# read csv file in r with spanish characters (´,ñ)

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I´m trying to add a column to a data frame in R. To do this, I imported a CSV file from Excel, which contains the id column (the same as the one I have in the data frame), and the column with the information I want to add to my data frame.

My problem is that my cvs has spanish characters (´, ñ), and when I use read.csv (as in the following example)

```
religion <- read.csv("religion.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".",
                     filled =TRUE, comment.char = "", strip.white = TRUE,
                     stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

the characters don't appear, but a question mark appears instead of the characters.

I have tried changing the encoding, with the following encodings:

UTF-8, latin1,

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "ES_ES.UTF-8")
```

But there is no difference.

I gladly appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the encoding used in the file? What OS are you using? A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful to see what's going on.

Comment: Does this work `dt<-data.table(a="ñ")`?

Comment: `filled` is not argument of read.csv, do you mean `fill`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `encoding` option inside your `read.csv` code

```
    religion <- read.csv("religion.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".",
                         filled =TRUE, comment.char = "", strip.white = TRUE,
                         stringsAsFactors = TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Remember, you can always check for documentation in R using `help(function)`

Answer (score 1):

You could expand off something like this:

```
DF<- data.frame(col1=c(1,2), col2=c("there is an ñ here", "there is an ´ here"))
#   col1    col2
#    1      there is an ñ here
#    2      there is an ´ here

DF$col2 <- chartr("ñ", "n", DF$col2)
DF$col2 <- chartr("´", "'", DF$col2)
DF
#  col1     col2
#   1       there is an n here
#   2       there is an ' here
```